# Regex for ipv4 address without 0.x.x.x if x != 0

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing a regex for ipv4 address, It's very interesting that Ubuntu and some RFC references state that 0.x.x.x if x != 0 are reserved, so invalid. What should be the more optimal regex for this? I have this one:

```
import re
matcher = re.compile(r'^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]|[1-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])){3}\Z^(0)(.0){3}\Z')
```

For example:

```
0.1.2.3 => should be invalid
1.0.0.0 => should be valid
0.0.0.0 => should be valid
```

Comment: Looks like you have two concatened patterns. (`\Z^` close to the end.)

Comment: It is not quite clear, could you please provide sample valid and invalid strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex that meets the requirements:

```
^(?!0+(?:\.0*[1-9][0-9]*){3}$)(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$
```

See [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SIjCb/1).

The main points are:

- `(?!0+(?:\.0*[1-9][0-9]*){3}$)` - a `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern matches:

  - `0+` - 1+ zeros
  - `(?:\.0*[1-9][0-9]*){3}` - 3 consecutive occurrences of
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `0*` - 0+ zeros
  - `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
  - `[0-9]*` - any 0+ digits
  - `$` - end of string.

Also, the octet regex now matches `0`, too:

- `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`:

  - `25[0-5]|` - `250` till `255`
  - `2[0-4][0-9]|` - `200` till `249`
  - `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` - `1` or `0` (optionally, 1 or 0 times) then any digit and then any 1 or 0 digits (an optional digit).

A [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kV6IdE):

```
import re

rx = """(?x)^   # start of string
         (?!    # start of the negative lookahead that fails the match if 
            0+(?:\.0*[1-9][0-9]*){3}$  # 0s appear only in the first octet
         )      # end of the lookahead
         (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)  # First octet regex
         (?:    # start of the non-capturing group
            \.  # a dot
            (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?) # octet
         ){3}   # repeated 3 times
         $      # end of string
"""
lst = ['0.1.2.3','1.0.0.0','0.0.0.0']
for s in lst:
    m = re.match(rx, s)
    if m:
        print("{} matched!".format(s))
    else:
        print("{} did not match!".format(s))
```

Output:

```
0.1.2.3 did not match!
1.0.0.0 matched!
0.0.0.0 matched!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the regex you looking for is:

`^(?:[01][0-9]?[0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.0{1,3}){3}$`

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/MrYzH3/1)